# iOS: How can I decide when UIView gets drawn?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview, visibility

I have added a `UIView` on my storyboard and connected the following code to it successfully (i.e. the thing draws on the screen when I load the app)

```
#import "UIView+DrawView.h"

@implementation DrawView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{ //Get the CGContext from this view
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //Set the stroke (pen) color
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    //Set the width of the pen mark
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);

    // Draw a line
    //Start at this point
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10.0, 30.0);

    //Give instructions to the CGContext
    //(move "pen" around the screen)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310.0, 30.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310.0, 90.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 10.0, 90.0);

    //Draw it
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

@end
```

What I would want however is to manually toggle this `UIView` to appear, which I cannot seem to do. I have tried the following:

1. Setting the `UIView` to Hidden in Storyboard and
2. Setting `DrawView.Hidden = YES;` to no avail, in both cases it draws immediately;

I hope that you can guide me on what I am missing here.

Comment: When you say, "in both cases it draws immediately", do you mean you see the drawing on screen, or that drawRect is executed?

Comment: If you set it to hidden in the storyboard, it should not show.  Are you sure the one defined in the storyboard is the only one being created?  (That is, no code initializes another `DrawView`.)

Comment: SOLVED:

Thank you rdelmar and @Phillip Mills for the help. Following your train of thought I decided to delete the UIview and to my dismay the drawRect was still executed. I noticed when clicking on the white background of the storyboard that the DrawView was connected to there as the custom class and the DrawRect was executed there. I must have mis-clicked earlier and attributed the custom class there as well, which I had no idea I could even do. Thanks again to you all.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the Custom Class property set to your class in the storyboard.

Comment: 1. it is set, otherwise the view would not even be drawn the expected way. 2. even without the custom class the hidden property should work

Comment: SOLVED: Thank you both for setting me on the right path as well. I had somehow managed to connect my custom class to the storyboard background itself which triggered the DrawRect on every boot.